# Google Collections on Android

Tags: java, android, guava, multimap

Has anyone ever used Multimaps on Android is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guava works as-is on Android.  What problems did you have?  Use the released JAR, not the Guava sources.  And as always, you should be using ProGuard as part of your build process to trim the size of your final binary down.

Comment: I didn't use it because of its huge size. How much does guava bloat up a project if you combine it with ProGuard for size reduzing?