# which data structure i should use in Java for 1 key multiple value

Tags: java, android

I have a RSS Feed in which i get date and news description, i want to add to arrange it in a way that, same date contains news of that day. for example,

```
date 1 - my news 1
       - my news 2
       - my news 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();  

//first list
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("orange");  
list.add("apple");  
list.add("banana");  
list.add("coconut");  
map.put("fruits", list);  

//seconds list
list = new ArrayList();
list.add("volvo");  
list.add("saab");  
list.add("honda");  
list.add("toyota");
map.put("cars", list);
```

and so on...

```
//to get from map   
List fruits = (ArrayList)map.get("fruits");   
List cars   = (ArrayList)map.get("cars");
```

Answer (score 5):

In core Java, you can use a map of list:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add("my news 1");
list1.add("my news 2");
list1.add("my news 3");

map.put("date 1", list1);
```

If you can use external libraries, Guava has a [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) concept which is doing that too, and [works fine on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168505/google-collections-on-android).

Answer (score 2):

Try guava library from google ( you can use it with android). This lib contains many useful data structures, such as multimap (you can look to multi map with array list backend) http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html):

```
map.put("date 1", "my news 1")
map.put("date 1", "my news 2")
map.put("date 1", "my news 3")
map.put("date 1", "my news 4")

List<String> news = map.get("date 1")
```